# display words at random position on click

Tags: javascript, html, random, onclick

It's the first time I ever post something on a forum. I'm new with javascript.

I found this : http://jsfiddle.net/6eTcD/2/ 
You type a word, and submit and then it appears randomly on the page.

HTML :

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var text = this.querySelector("input[type='text']").value;

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = text;
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
});
```

> Though I would like to choose myself the words that are gonna be
>   displayed, and I'd like them to appear when the button is clicked.
>   And at random positions. but not randoms words.

I tried to replace "text" with "words" and added

```
    function getRandomWord() {
  var words = [
    'Hello',
    'No',
    'Hi',
    'Banana',
    'Apple'
  ];
```

MY MODIFICATIONS :

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {


document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    function getRandomWord() {
  var words = [
    'Hello',
    'No',
    'Hi',
    'Banana',
    'Apple'
  ];

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = words;
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
});

    });
```

Anyway I don't think any of what I did could work. I'm new to this. 
Would any of you now?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to print the words one by one, not random.

```js
var words = [
  'Hello',
  'No',
  'Hi',
  'Banana',
  'Apple'
];
var visible = 0;

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = words[visible];
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    
    visible++;
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this won't print a random element from array. But first, 2nd, 3rd etc

Comment: My mistake, I overlooked that he wants them randomly.
But I will not delete my answer, maybe somebody need this kind of output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]` to select a random element from the array `items`.

I've used the code you provided in the JSFiddle link:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;
    
    var items = ['nothing', 'banana', 'apple', 'rasberry']
    var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
    
    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = item;
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Instead of searching for the string that is in the input box, the string will be randomly taken from the array of predefined strings `items`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a function which gives you a random value from the array.

```
function getRandomWord(){
  var words = [
    'Hello',
    'No',
    'Hi',
    'Banana',
    'Apple'
  ];

  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}
```

And how calling when your click handler will fire, just display the value returned by this method

Here is [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/6eTcD/89/)

Answer (score 0):

Working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eTcD/92/)

```
var allWords = [
  'Hello',
  'No',
  'Hi',
  'Banana',
  'Apple'
]; 

function getRandomWord(words) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  return words[randomIndex];
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.textContent = getRandomWord(allWords);

    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track here.  The first part you should look deeper into is your function `getRandomWord`.  In javascript, there is no such thing as implicit returns, which means you actually need to choose to return something.  Meaning you need to actually type the word `return`

```
    function getRandomWord() {
    var words = [
      'Hello',
      'No',
      'Hi',
      'Banana',
      'Apple'
    ];
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
 }


var text = getRandomWord();
```

Further down in your solution, you've added that `elem.textContent = words;` This will not work because the way you have it defined, `words` is actually an array.  There is more than one way to do this, but one way is to assign `elem.textContent = getRandomWord()`.

Now, when you you assign the text content to your function getRandomWord(), getRandomWord will run (or execute), and will assign whatever word comes out of getRandomWord to your text.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, the function you wrote had some major syntax and logical issues. Also as of now its printing all the elements of the words array. You can take out a random index and print that indexed word too if you want.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eTcD/94/)

```
var fullWidth ;
var fullHeight;
var words = [
    'Hello',
    'No',
    'Hi',
    'Banana',
    'Apple'
  ];
function getRandomWord() {
    var random = Math.floor( words.length * Math.random());
    var randomWord = words[random];  

    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.classList = "abc";
    elem.textContent = randomWord;
    elem.style.position = "absolute";
    elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
    elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
            $(".abc").remove();
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
};
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {


document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

     fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
     fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    getRandomWord();

    });
});
```