# display words at random position on click, in a container on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, display

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493513/display-words-at-random-position-on-click/) yesterday and was told to ask a new one to have an answer for a precision.

My code displays words on the page when the button is clicked.

It works perfectly, is it possible to contain it in a container ?

Cause i'd like this to only be displayed on mobile and when I reduce the browser page there's a huge scroll and all the words don't show in the window.

Just to try, I tried to contain it in a 300x300px box but the words appear everywhere. Is it possible either with the bootstrap grid or just any media queries, or like I did with any container ? Or is it another javascript rule ?

Thanks again !

```js
var words = [
  'Hello',
  'No',
  'Hi',
  'Banana',
  'Apple'
];
var visible = 0;

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.textContent = words[visible];
  elem.style.position = "absolute";
  elem.style.left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth) + "px";
  elem.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight) + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(elem);

  visible++;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to make this code: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4g07nd5z/ but it did not do the job

Answer (score 1):

I changed a little bit your code, in this way should work.

```js
var words = ['Hello','No','Hi','Banana','Apple'];
var visible = 0;
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  
  elem.className = "elem";
  elem.textContent = words[visible];
  
  document.body.appendChild(elem); // to get div sizes

  var left = Math.round(Math.random() * containerWidth); 
  var maxRight = containerWidth - (left + elem.offsetWidth + 5);
  
  if (maxRight < 0) {
    left -= Math.abs(maxRight);
  }

  var top = Math.round(Math.random() * containerHeight); 
  var maxBottom = containerHeight - (top + elem.offsetHeight + 5);
  
  if (maxBottom < 0) {
    top -= Math.abs(maxBottom);
  }

  elem.style.left = left + "px";
  elem.style.top = top + "px";
  
  container.appendChild(elem);

  visible++;
  
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="container"></div>
```